# PHP implementation for Map<List, List>

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

I need to design a data structure in PHP where I can map a collection of values to another collection of values. The use case of this is a map of subscriptions to users.

```
array(
    array('news', 'tech') => array(0, 1),
    array('news', 'tech', 'gossip') => array(2, 3, 4)
)
```

Is there an more optimal design we can use here? What would be an appropriate implementation in PHP?

Comment: So you have an array of values to use as the keys of a new array and then an array of values to use as the values of the new array?

Comment: How do you intend to use this data structure?

Comment: I suppose index can't be an object/array, it can be only String/Number. Rather you can think of having subscriptions to categories like array('news' => array(1,3,4), 'tech' => array(3,2))

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, users and subscriptions have a many-to-many relationship, and you'd like to be able to look up subscriptions for a given user, and vice versa, quickly?

If so, one design you could use is an object which encapsulates two multimaps, one that's `User -> Array<Subscription>`, and one that's `Subscription -> Array<User>` and maintains the two maps by updating them simultaneously in its `add` and `remove` methods (which would just take one user and one subscription as parameters).